# Number of sequences in Fasta Text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, fasta

Using Javascript, I want to calculate the number of sequences in Fasta text typed in a Textarea field. But I am really confused about how to do that.
For example, the below text should return that there are two sequences:

```
>seq Q
AGAAGTGAGTTTTGGATAGTAAAATAAGTTTCGAACTCTGGCACCTTTCAATTTTGTCGCACTCTCCTTG
TTTTTGACAATGCAATCATATGCTTCTGCTATGTTAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC

>seq C
TAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expression you can do this. Notice you have to use `g` (global) to make sure you count all the occurrences of sequences.

```js
let text = `>seq Q
AGAAGTGAGTTTTGGATAGTAAAATAAGTTTCGAACTCTGGCACCTTTCAATTTTGTCGCACTCTCCTTG
TTTTTGACAATGCAATCATATGCTTCTGCTATGTTAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC

>seq C
TAAGCGTATTCAACAGCGATGATTACAGTCCAGCTG
TGCAAGAGAATATTCCCGCTCTCCGGAGAAGCTCTTCCTTCCTTTGCACTGAAAGCTGTAACTCTAAGTA
TCAGTGTGAAACGGGAGAAAACAGTAAAGGCAACGTCCAGGATAGAGTGAAGCGACCCATGAACGCATTC`

let count = text.match(/>seq/g).length;
console.log(count);
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer for the case if instead of >seq there is something else?

Comment: You could include whichever pattern you like in between the back slashes. Ex: `text.match(/whichever_pattern/g).length;`